# Hibernate problems with multiple associations between two classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, hibernate-annotations

I use Hibernate with Playframework 1.2.4.

I have two classes : Examination and Question. A Question has always an attribute referring to an Examination. An Examination has always an attribute referring to a Question named specialQuestion and an attribute referring to a collection of Questions.

[image]

I aim to create Examinations with a special question affected to each one. When I create the Examination, I create this special question. The question is well created and persisted in the database, **the examination is persisted too but without the reference to the special question, the matching column is filled with null.**

I'm not sure about annotations. What is the problem ?

This static method returns a default special question

```
public static Question specialQuestion(Examination examination) {
        Question question = new Question();
        question.examination = examination;
        /* Other attributes affectations */
        return question;
}
```

Here it creates the Examination, affects the specialQuestion attribute and persists the object :

```
Examination examination = new Examination();
examination.specialQuestion = Question.specialQuestion(examination);
examination.save();
```

Class Examination contains those attributes :

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "examination", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Set<Question> questions = new HashSet<Question>();

@OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "examination")
    public Question specialQuestion;
```

Class Question contains :

```
@ManyToOne
@OneToOne
public Examination examination;
```

**EDIT :**

If if remove `mappedBy` in the specialQuestion `@OneToOne` annotation and the `@OneToOne` annotation for examination in Question class, I get errors : I could not load entity Examination anymore.

Here is the significant parts of the DDL :

```
CREATE TABLE `question` (
  `questionId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `examination_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`questionId`),
  KEY `FKBE5CA006E00B1456` (`examination_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=204 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `examination` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `specialQuestion` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Examination.specialQuestion should NOT have mappedBy. You cannot reuse a FK that specifies ownership of a Set, to also signify some particular question ... think of what data would be in the table for Question

Comment: and you regenerated your schema after you did your edit ? because "could not load Examination anymore" tells people nothing.

Comment: The difficulty is to extract significant informations from a complex application...
The application doesn't use schema generation. I write the database part separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution based on Thomas's answer :

Without modifying the schema, the classes turn into

Class Question :

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "examination_id")
public Examination examination;
```

Class Examination :

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "examination", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public Set<Question> questions = new HashSet<Question>();

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "specialQuestion")
public Question specialQuestion;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToOne` to the same property, since Hibernate needs to know which one is true.

And since the owning side is `Question` how should Hibernate know which of the questions is the special question? Think of it from a database point of view: storing the relation in the question table you'll eventually get multiple questions referencing the same examination. If those are unordered (a set) how would *you* determine the special question based on the data that is available?
Since you can't do that Hibernate won't do it as well.

To solve this you need to make `Examination` the owning side of `specialQuestion` and probably only a unidirectional relation as well, i.e. you don't map it in `Question` (remove the `mappedBy` and add a column for the reference to the examination table).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your answer (perhaps understanding difficulties with english...). Can you illustrate your answer with some code snippets ? Thx.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesLeDévéhat it's normally not that hard, just remove the `mappedBy` from `specialQuestion` and add a column for the special question id in the examination table. Oh and remove the `@OneToOne` from `examination` in the `Question` entity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating an additional entity which will essentially function as a 'join' entity between exam and question. This will give you the flexibility to assign the same question to multiple exams and to set the special question independently for each exam.

So for two exams consisting the same questions but with different special questions the table would look  like follows:

```
╔════════════════════════════════╗
║ exam_id question_id is_special ║
╠════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1        1          0          ║
║ 1        2          0          ║
║ 1        3          1          ║
║ 1        4          0          ║
║ 1        5          0          ║
║ 2        1          1          ║
║ 2        2          0          ║
║ 2        3          0          ║
║ 2        4          0          ║
║ 2        5          0          ║
╚════════════════════════════════╝
```

The basic mappings for the three entities are as below:

```
@Entity
public class Examination{

    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "examination")
    private Set<ExaminationQuestion> examQuestions;

    public Set<Question> getNormalQuestions(){
        Set<Question> questions = new HashSet<>();

        for(ExaminationQuestion eq: examQuestions){
            if(! eq.getQuestion.isSpecialQuestion()){
                questions.add(eq.getQuestion());
            }
        }

        return questions;
    }

    public Question getSpecialQuestion(){
        Question specialQuestion = null;

        for(ExaminationQuestion eq: examQuestions){
            if(eq.getQuestion.isSpecialQuestion()){
                specialQuestion = eq.getQuestion();
                break;
            }
        }

        return specialQuestion; 
    }
}

@Entity
public class ExaminationQuestion{

    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Examination examination;

    @ManyToOne
    private Questions question;

    private boolean specialQuestion;
}

@Entity
public class Question{

    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question")
    private Set<ExaminationQuestion> examQuestions;
}
```